# How to use Sprite class in Microsoft.DirectX to draw text and allow the mouse to rotate the screen?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, sprite, directx-9

I am using `Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D` and `Microsoft.DirectX` to render some data in 3D.

Now, I would like to draw text to indicate the height value inside the space. As shown the picture below:

[image]

Now I am facing two main problems:

Problem 1: As you can see, the draw text is set upside down. What can I do to make it to be show correctly?

Problem 2: I am getting `Direct3DXException` error when I tried to rotate the screen. The error message as per below:
[image]

Below is my code for `DrawText()` using `Sprite` class

```
Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D Device = new Device(0, DeviceType.Hardware, this.panel1,
                CreateFlags.HardwareVertexProcessing, presentationParameters);

private void Render()
{
    device.BeginScene();

    if(checkBox1.checked)
    {
        DrawText();
    }

    device.EndScene();
    device.SetTexture(0, null);
    device.Present();     
}

private void DrawText()
{
    Sprite fontsprite = new Sprite(device);
    fontsprite.Begin(SpriteFlags.AlphaBlend | SpriteFlags.ObjectSpace);
    _font = new Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.Font(device, 10, 10, FontWeight.Bold, 1, false, CharacterSet.Ansi, Precision.Default, FontQuality.ClearType, PitchAndFamily.DefaultPitch, "face1");
    _font.DrawText(fontsprite, "1.5 Km", 120, 15, Color.Black);
    _font.DrawText(fontsprite, "2.5 Km", 120, 25, Color.Black);
    _font.DrawText(fontsprite, "3.5 Km", 120, 35, Color.Black);
    fontsprite.Transform.Translate(120, 100, 100);
    fontsprite.End();
}
```

Need some help on resolving problem 1 and problem 2. Thank you.

**Update:** Problem 1 has been solved by myself. Now left problem 2 only.

Code to solve problem 1:

```
fontsprite.Transform = Matrix.RotationZ((float)Math.PI);
fontsprite.Transform *= Matrix.Translation(heightBoxSize, heightValue, heightBoxSize);
fontsprite.Transform.Translate(100, 100, 100);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because high memory consumption because you are creating new Sprite in every frame. (and 60 frames for each second?)
This problem happened where, rotating the screen using the mouse event, it will constantly update the result of device in frontsprite.

Therefore I suggest you to move part of the codes out.
Move the declaration part to global and then move initialization to Initialization() part.
Also move the fontsprite.End() to the Final() part.
I hopes that help.